# Creating connection to mongodb using node-vault in the application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to make a connection to MongoDB with a dynamically created username and password in `node-vault`.

For eg. in https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/databases/mongodb.html
Vault docs, there we create dynamic username and password to log in like:

```
$ vault read database/creds/my-role
Key                Value
---                -----
lease_id           database/creds/my-role/2f6a614c-4aa2-7b19-24b9ad944a8d4de6
lease_duration     1h
lease_renewable    true
password           8cab931c-d62e-a73d-60d3-5ee85139cd66
username           v-root-e2978cd0-
```

How can I have this behaviour using `node-vault` so that I can access MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

I did this using their `go` http client. Since `node-vault` is also http client using `node.js`. So i think procedure will be same.

1. First enable database(if it not enabled).

   `$ vault secrets enable database`.

   api for this: https://www.vaultproject.io/api/system/mounts.html#enable-secrets-engine.
2. Write mongodb config

   `$ vault write database/config/my-mongodb-database \
   plugin_name=mongodb-database-plugin \
   allowed_roles="my-role" \
   connection_url="mongodb://{{username}}:{{password}}@mongodb.acme.com:27017/admin?ssl=true" \
   username="admin" \
   password="Password!"`

   api for this: https://www.vaultproject.io/api/secret/databases/mongodb.html#configure-connection
3. Configure a role to create the database credential

   `$ vault write database/roles/my-role \
   db_name=my-mongodb-database \
   creation_statements='{ "db": "admin", "roles": [{ "role": "readWrite" }, {"role": "read", "db": "foo"}] }' \
   default_ttl="1h" \
   max_ttl="24h"`

   api for this: https://www.vaultproject.io/api/secret/databases/index.html#create-role
4. Generate a new credential by reading from the `/creds` endpoint

   `$ vault read database/creds/my-role`

   api for this: https://www.vaultproject.io/api/secret/databases/index.html#generate-credentials

Here https://github.com/kr1sp1n/node-vault/blob/master/example/mount_postgresql.js they do quite similar thing for `postgreSQL` in `node-vault` github repo.